# How to prevent HTTP localhost preview problem?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, localhost

I'm running a static web application in Eclipse + Tomcat and every time I run the application (Eclipse) and launched the project, I always encountered this problem `'Launching HTTP Preview at localhost' has encountered a problem`:

[image: Launching HTTP Preview at localhost has encountered a problem]

I have changed the port number numerous time. I am afraid that this action might harm the server itself. Can anyone tell me what's going on and how do I prevent this from keep happening?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 8080 port is already being used by some other process/application

You can change the port using below steps (In Eclipse)

1. In Servers Tab, Double click the Tomcat server to open the
   overview info
2. Under Ports section, HTTP/1.1 you can change the port you want and save it
3. Start the tomcat server, it should work

Thank you

Comment: I have tried it several times but it just keep having the same problem all over again somehow. for example, when I run Eclipse the next day it suddenly show same error.